# Using raw array text as input for array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization, deserialization

I need to be able to run some built in PHP functions on a large array which came from a corrupted wordpress database of which I have no backups except for a csv file. Specifically the wp_options table is what is messed up because some of the values in the array for the theme the site is using is nested a couple layers too deep and cut off about 100 option values in the `option_value db` cell.

I would like to be able to salvage the options I have in the original csv and add it to the stock value options that come from the dummy content for that theme and go from there to recoup what I can. Copy/pasting into the database is not working because not all of the values the theme uses are there so it is breaking a php script somewhere.

The format the text is in is like so:

> [data type]:[#items]:[data];
>   [another type]:[#items]:[more data];

so the real data would look like:

> a:3:{s:6:"abcdef";i:1:5;a:0:{}}

Is there some way I can take this raw text format and input it into a variable in php to use it as an array data type? Essentially I would loop through all the keys in the dummy content array and check if there was a value in the backup array and if so, replace it with the backed up value. If not, leave it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data:

```
a:3:{s:6:"abcdef";i:1:5;a:0:{}}
```

is an array that was serialized with the PHP serialize() function.

If you run:

```
$val = unserialize($serialized_value);
```

you will get the original values back.

Comment: Thank you!! This does exactly what I wanted.